# Can I install custom ROM on Android mobile having low internal memory?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, custom-roms, insufficient-memory

I want to install the latest custom ROM like Lollipop but my mobile has low internal memory, about 150MB.
Will that be a problem during the installation of the new custom ROM?
I have already rooted my phone and I'm worried that my mobile could get bricked.

Answer (score 0):

**No it will not effect**

Just place the ROM in sdcard and flash it through custom recovery by following given steps properly and flash the ROM which is developed for your device  otherwise you will end up having bricked your phone.

If your device have low RAM it may become laggy.

*Share the link of ROM that you want to flash and detail of your phone.May be we can help you little better*

Answer (score 0):

As long as the ROM was built for your device, it shouldn't be a problem. However, like what Ash-Ishh mentioned, you'll probably experience some lag.

You can also try looking up other forums to see if anyone else has flashed the same ROM on a device the same as yours and see if they're successful in the flashing.

Answer (score 0):

like previous comments, if it's built for your phone it'll boot up and work properly (unless the developer is a noob).

but your problem can be taken care of by one to these two methods

1. you can swap the internal and external memories by a script (you have to find that, sorry).
2. Partition your external memory card and format it to ext4 and with other script you can use this partition as your internal memory. (in this case if you remove your external memory card you'll get boot loops)

Answer (score 0):

If you have root, you can install a partition manager app like

- [Garted](https://pkgs.org/download/gparted) or
- [AParted](https://apkpure.com/aparted-sd-card-partition/com.sylkat.AParted)

And don't worry, you cannot brick the phone by flashing ROMs.

If the ROM is not designed for your device, it won't boot but you can flash the latest official room from your manufacturer.

And you mean the total space or is that 150 MB the user partition?
Go to Lineage OS as they have most ROMs for most devices

Do not install to SD card as mostly old phones do not support SD card boot. Some devices don't have even recovery and boot partition by default, so in order to have a bootloader to support such, it needs to be custom made to include extra functionality like SDcard and cloud boot, pxe.

But if the entire nand chip has just 150 MB,  maybe that is the RAM and not the ROM. Watch closer, take your time.

But if that phone has just 150 MB total nand space, well it won't even have a 3G network, so maybe the 150MB is the free space that you have provided the phone specs, look at About Phone in Settings.

Use an app like AIDA64.